# Which of these two usages of `wait()` and `exit()` is better?

Tags: linux, wait

Here is some usage of `wait()` and `exit()` that I understand from https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/200769b6c0dff6863089ea2a9ff4ea9ccbd15d0f/login-utils/login.c#L939

```
f(){
    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid) { 
        // parent part
        ...
        while (wait(NULL) == -1 && errno == EINTR) ;
        ...
        exit();
    }

    // common part, which is actually child part
    ...
}

f();

// common part 2, which is actually child part
...
```

Is it the same as this?

```
f(){
    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid) { 
        // parent part
        ...
        while (wait(NULL) == -1 && errno == EINTR) ;
        ...
        exit();
    }

    if (child_pid == 0) { 
        // common part, which is actually child part
        ...   

        // common part 2, which is actually child part
        ...         
    }
}

f();
```

Is the second one more easier to understand than the first? [That is what I feel (especially the above code is wrapped in a function, and a call to that function has other common code following it in `main()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887813/how-does-the-login-program-in-linux-invoke-a-login-shell), but I don't really know much about it.

Is there any reason or case where the first is better than the second?
In particular, why does the implementation of `login` (the first link above) choose the first way?

Comment: `child_pid < 0` isn't the child case, it's the error case. `fork()` returns 0 to the child.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really a question of what belongs inside a function, which is somewhat nebulous. But if your function is something like "put me into a new process that has its environment set up in some particular way", then it makes sense for that code to have a structure like:

```
void switch_to_child(){
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        exit_with_an_error();
    }
    if (pid > 0){
        wait_and_exit_in_parent();
    }
    set_up_child_environment();
}

initialize_stuff();
switch_to_child();
do_child_stuff();
```

On the other hand, if your function is something like "spawn a new process to do something", it makes more sense for the code to have a structure like:

```
void make_child(){
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        exit_with_an_error();
    }
    if (pid == 0){
        do_child_stuff();
        exit_in_child();
    }
}

initialize_stuff();
make_child();
wait_and_exit_in_parent();
```